# A word for worn pool table felt

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word describing a patchy appearance in something like hair, felt, grass, velvet etc- specifically surfaces, materials or areas comprised of a totality of much smaller, and usually upwardly angled fibers, hairs, blades and so forth, where there are areas of visible wear, damage or interruption. I've gone through the thesaurus ouroborus multiple times and cannot find the word I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would say trampled if it was grass, but perhaps frayed or mottled?

Comment: Why did you reject "worn"? Is it too generic?

Comment: "Moth-eaten" is a bit metaphorical but could work.

Comment: 'Worn' for pool table felt is apropos.

Comment: Look in a thesaurus for 'worn' if it is not good enough for you. Then come back and ask if a word you find works for a pool table.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions! In this instance, the word I'm looking for could apply to hair as well. To my mind, "worn", "moth-eaten", "threadbare" feel related to woven cloth, fabric, rather than a piled material, where individual fibers or areas could be worn down to a substrata, and the encompassing descriptor of that specific state would be X. The X is what I can't put my finger on. The sentence would be taking some poetic license, the comparison meant to infer disease or ill health, so where "blotchy" indicates the presence of unwanted patchiness, this would indicate an absence.

Comment: "baize with worn nap"? There are two types of baize or felt for pool tables: directional and non-directional. http://www.snookerdirect.co.uk/acatalog/About_pool_and_snooker_cloth.html

Comment: low nap because at the outset, the nap is "deep".

Comment: What exactly is wrong with *patchy*? (You used it in your question, and it seems to fit.)

Comment: A sample sentence will help!

Answer (score 5):

threadbare:

*having the nap worn off so that the thread shows*

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/threadbare#h1

Comment: I'm not sure that that is what happens to a worn [down, out] pool table cloth. Unless you use it beyond the stage of being _very_ worn. But then it wouldn't just _look_ worn.

Answer (score 0):

An animal with patchy fur may have mange and can be described as *mangy,* but *mangy* may also [mean:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mangy)

> having many worn or bare spots
>   *a mangy rug*

The word implies that the animal or item was once whole but has become patchy or scruffy-looking through disease or disrepair.